# Dynamically adjust image canvas for images

Tags: macos, graphics

I am new to Mac.

In Windows OS, I use MS Paint to dynamically adjust the canvas using the mouse by dragging the borders within the GUI to paste multiple cropped images into it to create a single new image.

Is there a way to do this in macOS using Apple default or paid apps where I can dynamically resize the canvas using the mouse? Manually entering percentages or dimensions to resize the canvas (either in the app or in terminal) is confusing to me to achieve the right canvas size.

Comment: This is what you find in Tools-> resize  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnZSQ.png not dynamic though. For paid apps, would Photoshop be an overkill?

Comment: @ankii: yes, I think photoshop would be an overkill. its too costly to use for such a simple requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Patina app (http://www.patinaapp.com/) in MAC.

This costs around 3.5 euros but it closely resembles MS Paint of Windows OS in terms of being able to dynamically resizing image canvas, adding text, etc

Sadly, they do not have a trial version to try it out beforehand. But I bought it and it seems fine as of now